# How to make a portal visible if player moves box to button in UE4.22?

Tags: unreal-engine4, game-development, unreal-blueprint

I'm making this game where the player needs to move a box onto a button to trigger an event that makes the portal visible and when the character enters the portal he taken to the next level. My problem is the button I'm able to open the portal if the character stands on it but not the box. Its a 2d top down game started as an empty project using blueprints.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You are on the correct road, you must do just a few changes only.
I understand that you have a trigger volume in the blueprint of the button, and you connected an event (e.g. OnComponentBeginOverlap) to open the portal. When you step with your character, it triggers, but not with the box. So the event is set ok.
But:

1. Create a new blueprint (AActor)
2. Add a static mesh component and on that component,  set the Static Mesh to the mesh you like (e.g. a box).
3. **Find in the details of the mesh component the Collision section, and set "Collision Presets > BlockAll".**

Then try again the game. The box you added probably was missing the collision.

You should double click on the mesh box on the "content browser" and go at the top:

**"Collision > Add Box Simplified Collision" and SAVE.**

I think now the portal will open.